# Android ListView igual do Instagram

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragment

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto no Android Studio, as telas do projeto são todas feitas em Fragment, estou utilizando o Material Design segui o tutorial [aqui](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/), e gostaria de fazer a tela principal um ListView parecido com o do Instagram. No meu caso seria, uma foto, e informações, e quando clicar na foto, abrir uma Activity ou Fragment(não sei qual seria o certo).
Peço a ajuda de vocês, pois os tutoriais que encontro na internet, estão muito ruins de entender, gostaria de preferência passo-a-passo.
Segue abaixo uma imagem que demonstra mais ou menos oque quero.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Você precisará de um [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) para gerenciar o conteúdo da ListView.

Exemplo:

Criar o adapter. Sugiro que leia a documentação para entender melhor a responsabilidade de cada método.

```
public class SeuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public SeuAdapter(Context context, List<String> lista){
        this.lista = lista;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return lista.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.seu_layout, null);
        //TODO preencher a view com as informações necessárias
        return view;
    }
}
```

Instanciar o adapter para usar na listView:

```
SeuAdapter seuAdapter = new SeuAdapter(getContext(), lista);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listview.set(adapter)
```

Listener para efetuar ação ao selecionar um item da lista, utilizando o [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //TODO pode utilizar a variavel position para pegar o objeto selecioando da lista.
            }
        });
```